# Intellij Idea not recognizing mutable field in Scala class, gives 'Reassignment to val' error

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, compilation, sbt

I have a Scala class with some var fields, let call it A:

```
class A extends AParent {
    var x: String = _
    ...
}
```

where AParent has some fields too:

```
abstract class AParent {
    var id: Long = _
    ...
}
```

When I try to use class A, to set a value on field x, I get `Reassignment to val` error. Why that happens when x is var?!
Maybe important piece of information is that class A and its parent are located in separate project, being imported via SBT.

Interestingly enough, I do not get the same "error" for any of the fields of AParent class. Only for fields that are directly in class A.

Furthermore, when I run `sbt clean compile` from command line, everything is ok, no compilation errors.
Also, when I go back to Idea and run the application, it runs nicely, does what it should be doing with no errors or warning whatsoever.

This looks like Idea bug to me, to be honest, but I haven't run into similar experiences so far.

Idea version:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.3 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-181.4892.42, built on May 8, 2018
...
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b38 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.13.4
```

Comment: If you think that this IntelliJ bug why do you report here? [Reporting Issues and Sharing Your Feedback](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reporting-issues.html)

Comment: I am looking for similar experiences before I do report it. I don't want to rush into reporting anything that looks odd to me.
Thanks for sharing culture full of understanding and acceptance.

Comment: Is there any problen when you compile with sbt without IntelliJ?

Comment: No. SBT compiles it just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried that in Intellij. The only change I needed to do was a default initialization of the `var`s, like:

```
class A extends AParent {
  var x: String = _
  def setId(newId: Long) {
    id = newId
  }
}

abstract class AParent {
  var id: Long = _
}

object Appl extends App {
  val a = new A()
  a.setId(234)
  println(a.id)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have that in my code, but I doesn't help. I haven't presented it in the question so I will update it now.

Comment: I just checked I have Intellij 2018.1.1 / 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b27 x86_64 - everything else is the same

Comment: It seems error appears only when AParent is in one project (imported via sbt as a lib) and A in other.
I moved A to the project where I am using it and compiler errors disappeared.